# Xcode stack views causing crash?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistackview

If I try to nest more than two stack views in one stack view Interface Builder slows to a crawl and I get a message saying an internal error has occurred and editing functionality may be limited.

Is there a workaround for this?

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both Xcode 7.2 and 7.3 beta (7D152p).

Comment: I have been using stackview pretty intensely the last 2 weeks and have not seen that sort of error.  Perhaps you left off a constraint that it needed to determine size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix this I just completely deleted everything in interface builder and started over from scratch :(

Now it seems to work just fine.

Comment: If you have the previous version of your storyboard/xib that exhibited the issue, can you please attach it to a new bug, filed at http://bugreport.apple.com? Even if you no longer have it, the output of running `sudo sysdiagnose Xcode` in Terminal could be helpful. Thanks!